# BlueStacks how to remove welcome tab?

Tags: bluestacks

I've installed BlueStacks v2.0.8.It's better than the old version.It have a problem.My internet is slow when I run BlueStacks.I found out the problem is welcome tab.It load a lot of data.I need a way to remove it.Can anyone help me please

Comment: Did you find a solution for this ?
If so, please let me know. Thanks

Comment: not yet.I got the 0.10.It no welcome tab.